# Update single records in query with form based textbox

Tags: ms-access

I am working with Access2013 and I have a query called PaidOrderQ with columns "SalesRep", "Customer" and "PaidAmount". I need to calculate the SalesRep's commission which isn't always the same percentage for each record. After reading through similar questions here I still haven't figured it out yet.

The way I thought doing it is to have a form called PaidOrderF with soucre is PaidOrderQ, a textbox called "CommRate" and a calculated field "Commission". The "Commission" gets calculated by "AmountPaid"*"CommRate".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the percentage for commission is calculated, but there are a few ways this can be done depending on how the percentage is calculated. The first would be if you can calculate the percentage that will be used automatically. Then you can add everything automatically (even if the percentage changes based on the item). If this is possible you can open the query up in DESIGN view. Then click onto a blank field and you can make a calculated field for example:

Commission: [AmountPaid]*[CommRate]

Now you can add the calculation for CommRate for example:

CommRate: IIf([AmountPaid]>200,.15,.2)

Which would make any the comm rate 15% over $200 and 20% under.
If not you can make Text boxes in a form (which would be unbound and add an after update vba code to multiply them together and change the value of a third text box, label etc.)

You may also want to add a column to the original table to show commission rate so the information would be stored for future reference.

Let me know if anything is unclear or you would like to see an example of the vba code

EDIT::

Storing information to a table:

This one will be very basic and you probably know most of this, but just in case I will include it because it is the most straight forward.

Add a column to the table you are working from by opening up the table in Design view (you can also make a temporary table by using a make table query if you are using a liked table or do not want to modify the structure, but it is better to put it in the main table if possible). Here you could make a query that includes all of the fields plus the additional calculated field that shows amount paid * commission. Then when you make a form based on the query you will enter in the commission rate and the form will both save the information and automatically update the field to give commission.

Linking another table by Primary ID -

If neither of those options work you could also create another table that shares a primary ID. This option will be more complicated, but is possible. (I would recommend not making it a true primary ID for the second table so it is easier to modify (Or have a true primary ID and the ID you will use to link ie. 3 total columns)). If this is the option you need I can go into more depth, but the disadvantage of this method is if there is no CommRate listed for a given record it will automatically hide the information (it is possible to avoid this, but again will be more complicated) so it will be easy to make a mistake.

VBA coding

VBA will be the most complicated solution, and has the largest disadvantages. First - You will have to loop all of the records at one time (or at least for one employee) and when you close the form you will lose everything. If there is any way to avoid this I would suggest doing so, but you could theoretically store the information in an array.

The Standard Way -
As I understand it your table looks like this:

```
SalesRep Customer PaidAmount
John      Eric      2040
Stacy     Brian     1020
Stacy     Eric      2004
etc.
```

You will want to open up your table in Design view and add a column "CommRate"
so it will look like:

```
 SalesRep Customer PaidAmount  CommRate
    John      Eric      2040
    Stacy     Brian     1020
    Stacy     Eric      2004
    etc.
```

The data type for CommRate should be Number - type Double - Now I would use Comm rate as a percentage - ie 10.2 = 10.2%, but you could also do .102 = 10.2% either one is fine (more on that later) save and close the table.

Now with the table selected use the create query wizard add all of the fields to the query, give the query a name and click modify the query at the end (or save it then open it up in design view). Now you will see each field in a column with the table listed below. Copy and paste the entry below to your query in one of the bank "field" locations:

for percentage ie 10.2=10.2%

```
Commission: [CommRate]*[PaidAmount]/100
```

for .102 = 10.2%

```
Commission: [CommRate]*[PaidAmount]
```

Now save and close the query.

Lastly you will select the query then click on create form. This will make a form based on the query. With this form you can add the CommRate individually and it will be saved for the future. You will see that when you add the CommRate the Commission field will automatically update and the table will get updated with the new value.

This is the standard way of doing this. Does this work for what you are doing?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't calculate the percentage automatically. Percentage has to be typed in by hand. I am at the point where I have the unbound text box in the form. How would an after update vba look like? When I change the percentage in the text box all records in the query change. I would like to change the active record only.

Comment: In that case-If you want to store the information it would be much better to add the information to the table (rather than the query) so the information is saved. The query will only pull information from the tables and modify it, but it will not be able to save the values. Is there a reason you are not able to add this to the table? You could solve this with an array, but when you closed it you would lose it (and you would not be able to see it all at once without a loop). If you are not able to add it to the table directly you could make another table and link by primary ID. Also see edit

Comment: I tried to avoid another table but that's probably the easiest way. Now I made the select query a make-table query and the "PaidOrderF" form source is the "PaidOrderT". I can change the "CommRate" text box to a different percentage but it does update all 33 records in the table instead the active one only. The new "CommRate" and "Commission" value isn't saved in the table. I think in need this after update vba here which I have no experience with.

Comment: Are you using a linked table? Ideally I would agree that you do not want to make another table. Are you able to add another column to the main table? The text box will always update all the records because the query is told to take the value of the text box regardless of the entry it is on. I will add the standard way to my comment and let me know if there is a constraint that prevents you from doing so and we can go from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience Robert. Unfortunately "SalesRep" "Customer" and "PaidAmount" are comming from a linked table which I can't modify.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate. Is there a primary key in the table?

Comment: Yes there is a primary key.

Comment: Ok see the new answer and let me know if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Alright well that is good news! The primary key will help a lot:
Ok here is how you can solve this with two tables.

First create a new table with three columns:
"ID" - Primary Key "RelatedID" - Number Long Int "CommRate" - Number Double

This table will basically just be used to "add on" the CommRate without changing the linked table.

Next you will make a query that includes  "SalesRep", "Customer" and "PaidAmount" from the linked table AND the "RelatedID" and "CommRate" from the new table.

When you view the query in design view you will see both tables above the list of the different fields and you will click on the primary key from the linked table and drag it to the "ReatedID" in the new table. From here it will open up a dialog asking about the relationship join. This part is the most important - You want to make the relationship a LEFT JOIN - You do this by saying you want to show ALL records from the Linked table and only the record from the New table that match. Basically this makes it so it will always show the records from the new table even if there is no entry that matches in the new table.

After you have that created you will just make a calculated field as before by copying:

```
Commission: [CommRate]*[PaidAmount]/100
```

to a new field on the query design

From here everything is set up and you can create a form based on the query you just made - I would delete the field "RelatedID" from the FORM (or the Query the relationship is what links it so its not necessary it is just a good double check) so you don't change it.

How it works - Now when you cycle through the entries you can add the commission rate directly to the form. - This will make a new entry in your new table that shows the primary ID of the transaction and the commission rate for that sale. This will update the calculated field and show you the commission. Then when you view it it will save the values individually without changing your original table.

Keep me posted if you need more help on how to do this. It can be a little tricky the first time you do it.

Comment: I created the form based on the query and as I understand this query is the control soucres for the form as well. If I try to enter a number in the commission rate it won't let me. The field stays empty. I think I miss something. With this setting I try to enter the commission rate into the query which isn't possible.

Comment: Well not quite - You will be entering the information into the table the query just organizes the information so that you can enter it in a little easier. I would check on the query you made. Does it show any results? Can you edit the information from the query itself? Does the query update the information when you do so? The query will be the hardest part of this. Make sure you have a left join for the records.

Comment: It says on the very bottom left "This recordset is not updateable" If i try to enter anything in the form. I investigated in that and I was mistaken. The linked table doesn't have a primary key. I think that's the reason it doesn't let me update records.

Comment: In that case your only option may be to make a local table using a make table query then use the first solution . It will work fine, but it will be hard to add new entries later, because you will need to update the local table. Unless there is a unique identifier there is no sure way to link the information together.